# Whats wrong with my filesystem watcher code VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, antivirus

when my file system watcher detects a virus a dialog shows but when i click the delete file option it says its open in my program but in the filesystem watcher when i add the openfiledialog.Dispose function it doesnt show my dialog so heres the code can somone provide a fix? code below.

```
Private Sub FileSystemWatcher1_Changed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FileSystemWatcher1.Changed
    Try
        Detect.Labellastreal.Text = e.FullPath
        ListBox3.Items.Add(Detect.Labellastreal.Text)
        Me.OpenFileDialog3.FileName = ""
        Dim scanbox As New TextBox
        scanbox.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\VirusList.dat").ToString
        Dim md5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim f As New FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, &H2000)
        f = New FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, &H2000)
        md5.ComputeHash(f)
        Dim hash As Byte() = md5.Hash
        Dim buff As New StringBuilder
        Dim hashByte As Byte
        For Each hashByte In hash
            buff.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", hashByte))
        Next
        f.Close()
        If scanbox.Text.Contains(buff.ToString) Then
            Me.OpenFileDialog3.FileName = e.FullPath
            Detect.ShowDialog()


            WriteToLog("Virus detected")

        End If

    Catch exception1 As Exception
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1)
        Dim ex As Exception = exception1
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: its all layed out wrong my first time posting... From Private Sub is the start of the code sorry

Comment: You are creating two `FileStream`s, immediately abandoning the first one.

Comment: so what do i do to fix my code?

Comment: thank you for the reply btw

Comment: Do not open two filestreams when you need one.

Comment: and then when i click the delete button it shouldnt say its open in my program?

Comment: so what should i remove dude:                                                                            Dim f As New FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, &H2000) or 
            f = New FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, &H2000)

Comment: Remove `f = New FileStream(...)` since you already create a new `FileStream` when you create your variable (the `Dim f As New FileStream(...)` line).

Comment: its working but the dialog is poping up slower is there any ways to speed the process thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **don't even bother using that code**. `FileSystemWatcher` is unreliable, and fails lots of the time.

Secondly, remove `f = New FileStream(e.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, &H2000)`, as you're calling it twice.

Lastly, for a Visual Basic anti-virus with real-time protection, I recommend you use **this code:**

```
Private Function GetMD5String(ByVal strFilename As String) As String
        Dim MD5 As String = GetMD5String(strFilename)
        Dim cMD5 = Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create
        Dim bytHash As Byte()
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim scanbox As New TextBox
        scanbox.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("viruslist.txt").ToString
        Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName = strFilename

        Using cStream As New IO.FileStream(strFilename, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.Read)

            bytHash = cMD5.ComputeHash(cStream)
        End Using

        For Each c In bytHash
            sb.Append(c.ToString("X2"))
        Next

        If scanbox.Text.Contains(sb.ToString) Then
            Detect.ShowDialog()
            WriteToLog("Malicious exploit detected.")
            Quarantinevb.ListBox1.Items.Add(strFilename)
        End If

        Return sb.ToString



    End Function
```

Works well and is reliable.